# Visual C# Form right click button

Tags: c#, winforms, click, mouseevent

I am trying to make a minesweeper type game in visual c# and I want to have different things happen when I right click and left click a button, how do I do this?

I have tried this code but it only registers left clicks:

```
    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Left");
        }
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Right");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You already have the correct answer, so no need to rewrite that. I wrote my own minesweeper a few weeks ago and asked an [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485779/capture-simultaneous-right-and-left-click-event-triggers-on-label) that might help you. It's how to create the "click both mouse buttons at the same time on a number to unveil all the covered boxes surrounding it" function. If you already know how to do this, just ignore me :)

Comment: Cool, that might come in handy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to use the `MouseUp` or `MouseDown` event instead of the `Click` event to capture right click.

Comment: Also check that `eventArgs.button == MouseButtons.Right`

Answer (score 2):

Just try with `button1_MouseDown` event instead of `button1_MouseClick` Event.It will solve your problem.

```
 private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
          //do something
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
          //do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Button is reacting only for `MouseButtons.Left` not for `MouseButton.Right` and not even for middle.

```
void Select(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    /* var btn = sender as CardButton;*/

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (this.Selected == false)
        { 
            this.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Selected = false;
        }
    }
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (this.Selected == false)
        {
            this.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Selected = false;
        }
    }

    Draw();
}
```